# jquery table data

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

I have the following table

```
<thead>

<tr>

<th>Account ID</th>

<th>Code</th>

<th>Date Created</th>

<th>Date Expires</th>

<th>Balance</th>

<th>Approve</th>

<th>Deny</th>

</tr>

</thead>

<tbody>

<tr class="test">

<td class="giftcardaccount_id"><span>35083</span>

</td>

<td class="code"><span>xxxxxxxxx</span>

</td>

<td><span>2012-06-28</span>

</td>

<td><span>2012-06-28</span>

</td>

<td><span>9.0000</span>

</td>

<td><Button id="approval_0" type="submit" class="save-button btn success floatRight" ><span>Approve</span> </button>

</td>

<td><Button id="deny_0" type="submit" class="save-button btn danger floatRight" ><span>Deny</span> </button>

</td>

</tr>

<tr class="test">

<td class="giftcardaccount_id"><span>35084</span>

</td>

<td class="code"><span>xxxxxxxx</span>

</td>

<td><span>2012-06-28</span>

</td>

<td><span>2012-06-28</span>

</td>

<td><span>9.0000</span>

</td>

<td><Button id="approval_1" type="submit" class="save-button btn success floatRight" ><span>Approve</span> </button>

</td>

<td><Button id="deny_1" type="submit" class="save-button btn danger floatRight" ><span>Deny</span> </button>

</td>

</tr>

</tbody>
```

what I am trying to do is that if someone clicks on the approved, I want to get all the row data, with the information that the approved button was clicked. Same with deny button. How would I do that with jquery.

thanks

```
**EDIT**
did this but not sure how to get the button that was clicked. I can get the data by this, but I dont know if the deny was clicked or submit was?
```

$('.test').click(function() {

```
    var id = $(this).children('.giftcardaccount_id').text();


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.test').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).find('.giftcardaccount_id:first > span').text();
});
```